# What does AsynchronousExit() do?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

Here's the code that I am referring to:

```
public partial class SplashScreen : Window
{
    public SplashScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BitmapImage splashScreenImageSource = new BitmapImage();
        splashScreenImageSource.BeginInit();
        splashScreenImageSource.UriSource = 
            new Uri("Resources/world_splash.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        splashScreenImageSource.EndInit();

        splashScreenImage.Source = splashScreenImageSource;
    }

    public void AsynchronousExit()
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Does `AsynchronousExit` ever get called? I'm not sure if `AsynchronousExit` is some sort of .NET Service that runs if code if available or if it needs to be called explicitly.

Comment: You could put a breakpoint there to see if it's called. However, from your code, it doesn't look like it's called. What it does is run the `worker_DoWork` method on a background thread.

Comment: As of right now, it does Thread.Sleep(5000)

Comment: I think what keyboard means is that you forgot the code that links the `AsynchronousExit` method to... something...

Comment: If you've copied this code from somewhere, a link might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you defined it, it does nothing; it's a method *you* wrote that the framework has no knowledge of.

If it's getting called, it's because you called it or you told the framework to call it.  However, there is nothing that the framework is doing with this; a search for "[.NET AsynchronousExit](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20asynchronousexit)" doesn't return anything relevant or that something like this even exists in the framework.